# What happens if PHP's session garbage collection takes a long time?

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection

If I implement my own [SessionHandlerInterface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) and the `gc` function takes a really long time to complete, will it make the web request that started the `gc` appear to hang to the user? Is there any way to make the `gc` not block the web request that started it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not directly.

If you have a GC implementation that takes a long time to complete it's much preferable to run it as a periodic background task independent of user requests.